# Bitwise operations on 64-bit data type (long long) in C?

Tags: bitwise-operators, long-long

Here is some code.

```
long long bitmap2 = 1;
printf("%d\n", bitmap2 & 1);
```

The output is 0, but I am expecting 1. How can I fix this? (I have tried 1LL instead of 1 and uint64_t instead of long long; both gave the same answer of 0.)

Answer (score 2):

What you're currently seeing is **undefined behaviour**; you need to ensure that the format specifier and the argument match.  So use one of the following:

```
printf("%lld\n", bitmap2 & 1);
printf("%d\n", (int)(bitmap2 & 1));
```

See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf for complete documentation for `printf`.

However, most compilers should warn you if there's a mismatch between the `printf` format string and the types of the arguments that you supply.  For example, if I compile your code in GCC with the `-Wall` flag, I get the following:

```
warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long long int'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `printf("%d\ll", bitmap2 & 1)` instead of `printf("%d\n", bitmap2 & 1)` if you want to print a long long.